Apex Trigger: account rating not updating based on case status count
Based on the case status, update the account rating when the case status is closed only.
If the closed case is 1 then the rating is cold and if the closed case is 2 then the rating is hot.
I have written the below code but it seems it is not working.
public with sharing class AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusClass {
    
    public static void checkCaseStatus(List<Case> caseList, Map<Id, Case> oldMap){
        System.debug(' rsn Trigger is executing : ' + Trigger.isExecuting);
        
        Set<Id> caseIDs = new Set<Id>();
        
        if(!caseList.isEmpty()){
            for(Case cc : caseList){
                if(oldMap != null){
                    Case oldCases = oldMap.get(cc.Id);          // to get old cases
                    
                    if(cc.AccountId != oldCases.AccountId){     // when user changes parent account of case
                        System.debug('rsn 1: Account changed for Case - Old Account: ' + oldCases.AccountId + ', New Account: ' + cc.AccountId);
                        caseIDs.add(oldCases.AccountId);
                        caseIDs.add(cc.AccountId);
                    }
                    else if(oldCases.IsClosed != cc.IsClosed){    // for update
                        System.debug('rsn 2: Case status changed - Case: ' + cc.Id);
                        caseIDs.add(cc.AccountId);
                    }
                    else if(cc.IsClosed == true){              // insert, delete, undelete
                        System.debug('rsn 3: Case closed - Case: ' + cc.Id);
                        caseIDs.add(cc.AccountId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        List<AggregateResult> filteredCase = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) numClosedCases 
                                              FROM Case WHERE AccountId IN :caseIDs  AND IsClosed = true  GROUP BY AccountId];
        
        System.debug('rsn 5: Filtered cases: ' + filteredCase);
        
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        
        if(!caseIDs.isEmpty()){
            System.debug('rsn 4: Case IDs to process: ' + caseIDs);
            
            
            for(AggregateResult ar : filteredCase){
                System.debug('rsn 6: AggregateResult: ' + ar);
                Id accountId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId');
                Integer numClosedCases = (Integer)ar.get('numClosedCases');
                String accountRating = '';
                if(numClosedCases >= 2){
                    accountRating = 'Hot';
                } else if(numClosedCases == 1){
                    accountRating = 'Cold';
                }
                // Fetch existing Account record and update rating
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Id = accountId;
                acc.Rating = accountRating;
                accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
            }
            
            System.debug('rsn 7: Accounts to update: ' + accountsToUpdate);
            if(!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
                update accountsToUpdate;
            }
            System.debug('rsn 8: Accounts updated');
        }
    }
}

Trigger Code hare:
trigger AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusTrigger on Case (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
//    AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusClass.checkCaseStatus(trigger.new, trigger.oldmap);

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusClass.checkCaseStatus(Trigger.new, trigger.oldmap);
    }
    
    else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusClass.checkCaseStatus(Trigger.old, null);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete)){
        AccountRatingUpdateViaCaseStatusClass.checkCaseStatus(Trigger.new, null);  //A insert and undelete 
    }

}

it is executing but not updating values. Can anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Try this simple code from https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-5S_mCtpgcYLS8ZnOB and extend if for various scenarios. it should work as long as you're updating case to closed and you've after update trigger event calling this method.

Try below one by creating a custom field IsClosed__c (Checkbox field) should be {unchecked by default} on Case object, it will work for all the scenarios in bulk(Insert, Update(which includes Reparenting),Delete and Undelete).

Trgr: -> 
----
trigger AccountRatingTrgr on Case(after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete){
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            AccountRatingTrgrCls.AccountRatingTrgrMethod(Trigger.New,Trigger.OldMap);
        }else if(Trigger.isDelete){
            AccountRatingTrgrCls.AccountRatingTrgrMethod(Trigger.Old,null);
        }else{
            AccountRatingTrgrCls.AccountRatingTrgrMethod(Trigger.New,null);
        }
    }
}
Modular Class: ->
-------------
public class AccountRatingTrgrCls{
    public static void AccountRatingTrgrMethod(List<Case> caseList,Map<Id,Case> oldCaseMap){
        String accountRating;
        Set<Id> setOfAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Decimal> accountMap = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
        List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        if(caseList!=null && caseList.size()>0){
            for(Case cses : caseList){
                if(cses.IsClosed__c){
                    if(oldCaseMap==null){
                        setOfAccountIds.add(cses.AccountId);
                    }else{
                        if(cses.AccountId != oldCaseMap.get(cses.Id).AccountId){
                            setOfAccountIds.add(cses.AccountId);
                            setOfAccountIds.add(oldCaseMap.get(cses.Id).AccountId);
                        }else{
                            setOfAccountIds.add(cses.AccountId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(setOfAccountIds.size()>0 && setOfAccountIds!=null){
                for(AggregateResult agr : [Select AccountId, Count(Id) countOfCaseIds FROM Case WHERE AccountId IN: setOfAccountIds GROUP BY AccountId]){
                    accountMap.put((Id)agr.get('AccountId'),(Integer)agr.get('countOfCaseIds'));
                }
            }
            accountList = [Select Id,Rating FROM Account WHERE ID IN: setOfAccountIds];
            if(accountList.size()>0 && accountList!=null){
                for(Account accounts : accountList){
                    if(!accountMap.isEmpty() && accountMap!=null){
                        accountRating='';
                        if(accountMap.containsKey(accounts.Id)){
                            if((Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)==0){
                                accountRating = '';
                            }else if((Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)>0 && (Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)<=2){
                                accountRating = 'Cold';
                            }else if((Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)>2 && (Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)<=6){
                                accountRating = 'Warm';
                            }else if((Integer)accountMap.get(accounts.Id)>6){
                                accountRating = 'Hot';
                            }
                            accountListToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=accounts.Id,Rating=(String)accountRating));
                        }else{
                            accountListToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=accounts.Id,Rating=''));
                        }
                    }else{
                        accountListToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=accounts.Id,Rating=''));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(accountListToUpdate.size()>0 && accountListToUpdate!=null){
                UPDATE accountListToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}

Documentation is below:

The method first checks if the caseList is not null and has at least one element.
It then iterates through the caseList and checks if each case is closed. If so, it adds the account ID to a set of account IDs.
If the oldCaseMap is not null, it checks if the account ID of the updated case has changed. If so, it adds both the old and new account IDs to the set.
The method then queries the Case object to count the number of cases for each account ID in the set.
It retrieves the list of accounts corresponding to the account IDs in the set.
For each account, it checks if the count of cases is greater than 0. If so, it determines the account rating based on the count:
0 cases: rating is empty
1-2 cases: rating is 'Cold'
3-6 cases: rating is 'Warm'
more than 6 cases: rating is 'Hot'
The method updates the account rating and adds the updated account to a list.
Finally, it updates the list of accounts with the new ratings.


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to explain your code further so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or are struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details to benefit the community?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@TusharJadav
Please check the doc and let me know if this reasoning is understandable to you.
